# What governs the order in which assemblies are loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly, jit

Consider a console application which references two assemblies `FooAssembly` and `BarAssembly` (in addition to the system assemblies). In addition, `BarAssembly` references `FooAssembly`. I added a handler for the `AssemblyLoad` event for my application's `AppDomain` with a breakpoint to see the order in which the assemblies are loaded. Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += OnLoad;
    }

    static void OnLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs e)
    {
        // do nothing, but include break-point
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooAssembly.FooClass f = new FooAssembly.FooClass();
        BarAssembly.BarClass b = new BarAssembly.BarClass();
    }
}
```

With this setup, `FooAssembly` loads first, `BarAssembly` loads second.

However, when I change my Main method to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BarAssembly.BarClass b = new BarAssembly.BarClass();
    FooAssembly.FooClass f = new FooAssembly.FooClass();
}
```

`BarAssembly` loads first, `FooAssembly` loads second.

And this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BarAssembly.BarClass b = new BarAssembly.BarClass();
}
```

`BarAssembly` loads first, `FooAssembly` loads second.

So it seems to me that assemblies are loaded by the JIT compiler in the order in which they are referenced by a method it needs to compile (in this case `Main`).

Why doesn't `FooAssembly` always get loaded first since `BarAssembly` also references it?

I am relatively new to the concept of `AppDomains` with lazy-loaded assemblies, so any explanation and/or documentation would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can get some information here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268(v=vs.110).aspx. You need to understand the assembly probing of .NET.

Comment: The second case is not different from the third.  Your assumption that creating FooClass was necessary to get FooAssembly loaded is not accurate.  The jitter is apt to look ahead at the BarClass constructor to see if it can be inlined for example.

Comment: @HansPassant you are correct. When I add `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` to `BarClass` ctor and run case 3, `FooAssembly` does not load until ctor call.